# how to save a file and give it the same name as the listview item thats clicked

Tags: android, arrays, listview, save

i have this code that fills a listview but also i need to know how to fill textview with a string from the same array that fills the listview, the reason i need this is i have a code that saves files to internal or external memory, but i dont know how to set the name other then writing it there i want to be about to set it from the same array that fill the list  eg listview is story one, story two and so on, when they click one story one i want the name of the file to be saved the same as the listitem name that they click on ..... here is my code

```
    public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

String[] list = null;
String[] listITEMS = list;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
setContentView(R.layout.menu_list);

TextView textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
textview.setText(listITEMS[0]);

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, getItems());
setListAdapter(adapter);

ListView storyListDownload = getListView();
storyListDownload.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


        if  (position == 0) {
            Intent buttona = new Intent(view.getContext(), StoryOne.class);
            startActivity(buttona);
        }


    }
});

}

private List<String> getItems() {
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
JSONArray jArray = connectToServer("http://10.0.2.2/textures_story_list.php");
JSONObject json_data = null;
for(int i=0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
    try {
        json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
        list.add(json_data.getString("story_name"));
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
return list;
}

public static JSONArray connectToServer(String address) {
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(address);
try {           
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    InputStream is = entity.getContent();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"UTF8"),8);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(reader.readLine() + "\n");
    String line="0";
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line + "\n");
    }
    is.close();
    String result = sb.toString();
    JSONArray array = new JSONArray(result);
    return array;
} catch(Exception e){
    //Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
    return null;
}
}   
}
```

i allready know how to save file but dont know how to give it a name other then writing it myself.... and the file extentions need to be .json aswell, i was hoping i could use the working listvoew but fill the textview with the same name atm
any help would be greatly appreciated